# vbObjectError how to use this one into c# code

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

Let me know how to use this **"vbObjectError"**  in c# code:
//This is my VB code

```
Public Enum CryptoErrors
    ErrorAquiringContext = vbObjectError + 1056
    ErrorCreatingHash = vbObjectError + 1057
    ErrorCreatingHashData = vbObjectError + 1058
    ErrorDerivingKey = vbObjectError + 1059
    ErrorEncryptingData = vbObjectError + 1060
    ErrorDecryptingData = vbObjectError + 1061
    ErrorInvalidHexString = vbObjectError + 1062
    ErrorMissingParameter = vbObjectError + 1063
    ErrorBadEncryptionType = vbObjectError + 1064
End Enum
```

Comment: Just don't.  In C# you throw exceptions, you don't use error codes.

Answer (score 2):

You could translate it literally as:

```
public enum CryptoErrors
{   
     ErrorAcquiringContext = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbObjectError + 1056,
     ...
}
```

in which case you need a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.

If you don't want to take a dependency on Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, you could define your own C# constant instead:

```
public const int VBObjectError = -2147221504;
```

But I'd question why you'd need it in a C# application.  Constants offset from `vbObjectError` normally correspond to an HRESULT and are used in a VB `Err.Raise` statement.

In C# you'd just throw an exception.

Comment: One would need this constant if one were writing code in C# for consumption in VB.  Of course, if one were doing that, one would probably (1) already have a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and (2) already know the answer to the question.